# Handling Common Identity and Migration for Multiple DBContexts with a single Database in EFCore

Tags: entity-framework-core

In **project Three**, I have the **ProjectOneDBContext** and **ProjectTwoDBContext** pointing to the **same database** for both the web applications together. I get an issue handling the **same Migration assembly** & **and to have Common Identity tables**

In the **ProjectOne's Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectOneDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            databaseConnectionString,
            o => o.MigrationsAssembly(projectThreeMigrationAssembly)),
        ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
        ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

In the **ProjectTwo's Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectTwoDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            databaseConnectionString,
            o => o.MigrationsAssembly(projectThreeMigrationAssembly)),
        ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
        ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

**ProjectOneDBContext.cs in ProjectThree**

```
public class ProjectOneDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
...
  public void ConfigureDevelopment(...)
  {
   ...
   context.Database.Migrate();
   ...
  }
...
}
```

**ProjectTwoDBContext.cs in ProjectThree**

```
public class ProjectTwoDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
    ...
      public void ConfigureDevelopment(...)
      {
       ...
       context.Database.Migrate();
       ...
      }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProjectTwoDBContext didn't have to inherit from the IdentityDbContext for the ProjectOneDBContext has inherited it.